# Professor vs Grad Student PI for PhD rec letter

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I am nominally in a Professor X's lab, but I work with and communicate with his PhD Student Y most of the time. Would it be looked down upon for Y to write me a LoR for grad school, since even though he knows me better, he is only a grad student/would be a fresh PhD by the time I get around to applying? Should I plan to ask X for a rec letter even though I don't directly work with him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming X has high reputation, you should ask X. If (s)he does not know your work already, (s)he can ask Y for details.

Comment: Not only that, I think it would be encouraging for Y to actively inform X of the OP's work, and X can write the letter based on that...

Comment: @RamPadmanabhan: Most probably X already knows what to write.

Comment: I mean in terms of how well Y knows the OP, which is likely better than how well X knows the OP.

Comment: @RamPadmanabhan: I assumed that X knows what is going on in the lab.

Answer (score 1):

A recommendation from a professor is worth more than a recommendation from a PhD student. X also has more experience writing recommendation letters than Y, and probably has a better idea of what makes a good letter from reading the letters of applicants. X may be more aware of your work than you might realize from talking to Y. Anyways, it's best to ask X to write and sign the letter, possibly with Y providing input or assistance in writing.